# Stackblitz example not working in Angular docs:

Tags: angular, npm, stackblitz

I'm trying to examine the [example](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dynamic-form/stackblitz.html) provided in the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form). When I load the StackBlitz, it fails to start. The terminal readout is:

```
~/projects/zesusx--run
❯ npm install --legacy-peer-deps && npm start
npm ERR! Failed to fetch

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.npm/_logs/2023-06-12T15_42_11_032Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Works for me. But while you mention errors in angular docu here and not there?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Oh, it's started working for me now. Magic. Thanks for the help!